# Change the color of the button to green from default grey?

Tags: html, css

Just a quick question, currently the button is grey with red text displayed inside and I want to make the button Green with white text displayed.

The CSS i am using is

```
.uploadmorefiles{
     color: red;
}
```

for button:

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="uploadmorefiles"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Click here to upload more file</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [button type](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) "Success" provided by Bootstrap framework itself.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.uploadmorefiles{
     background-color: green;
     color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[LiveOnFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/fassd3d3/3/)

```
.uploadmorefiles {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: I did that made the button green with text white however some of the outside is tiny grey, how I make the whole buttion green? @Mostafa Baezid

Comment: @WaqarMalik update my code. If you don't want the outline onclick I have update my fiddle also take a look

Answer (score 0):

```css
.uploadmorefiles{
     color: white;
     background : green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in HTML are grey by default and your rule for color is changing the color of the text inside the button.

```
.uploadmorefiles{
 color: white;
background: green;
```

}